# Integrate reactjs with postgraphile

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

Am new to reactjs trying to integrate postgres with reactjs. Is there any way to integrate postgraphile with reactjs.

If so, please help me with a code or tutorial link.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a collection of app examples using PostGraphile, some of these involve React:

https://github.com/graphile/postgraphile/wiki/App-Examples

Also check out https://github.com/graphile/examples and https://github.com/graphile/bootstrap-react-apollo

Comment: 2020 update: there's a full-stack fully formed example now at https://github.com/graphile/starter

Answer (score 1):

While there's already an accepted answer here, it missed stating something obvious: the way you "integrate reactjs and postgraphile" is by using a GraphQL client library (eg. Apollo, Relay, Lokka, etc.) in your React application to access the API that postgraphile creates.